# Spring @ResponseBody Json Cyclic Reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, bidirectional-relation

I am trying to use Spring 3.x `@ResponseBody` to generate json/xml response, I am using JPA 2.0 ORM when there is many-many relation b/w tables then json is throwing LazyInitializationException

If I give "eager fetch" then it is going into cyclic reference.

Comment: This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I've also run into this issue, and I've had to solve it by writing a custom `ObjectMapper` and `JsonSerializer` that dealt with relationship.

Comment: can anybody give solution to my problem, this is still holding my development

Comment: I see two solutions that have been posted. Have you tried either?

Comment: custom wrapper I didnt tried, its the last option I am trying to consider, yes I am calling the methods to initialize the child - like user.getGroups() - where groups has many-many relationship and it again has userList which I cant intialize because it will cause cyclic problem again.

Comment: Do you need all of these references on your response body?

Comment: I dont need but @ManytoMany annotation is creating that, I just need user and list of groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar problem: [Jackson - serialization of entities with birectional relationships (avoiding cycles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc)

So the solution is to upgrade to Jackson 2.0, and add to classes the following annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
                  property = "@id")
public class SomeEntityClass ...
```

Then the problem is that Spring doesn't work with Jackson 2.0. This has been solved in the following way:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
          class="own.implementation.of.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc
             .annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="requireSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

And the `own.implementation.of.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` is based on this:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java?format=ok

But use ObjectMapper and other Jackson classes from Jackson 2.0 instead of Jackson 1.*

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your comments, just create a custom `Serializer`.

Your `JsonSerializer`.  You can have these for each object type you're trying to serialize.

```
public class MyObjectJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyObject> {

@Override
public Class<MyObject> handledType() {
    return MyObject.class;
}

@Override
public void serialize(MyObject myObject, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeNumberField("id", myObject.getId());
    // whatever else you need
    jgen.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

Your `ObjectMapper`.

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

public MyObjectMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("My Module", new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT"));
    module.addSerializer(new MyObjectJsonSerializer());

    this.registerModule(module);
}
```

}

And then in your spring-config.xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="myObjectMapper" class="com.manne.app.objectmapper.MyObjectMapper" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are serializing an ORM-managed object to JSON, but haven't initialized all of the child associations, leading to the `LazyInitializationException`, as your Controller doesn't have a handle to the DB connection.  2 choices:

1. Initialize all of the objects' child associations in the DAO layer
2. Convert the ORM-managed object to a TO and pass that to the Controller for conversion to JSON

Comment: In my scenario I have users and groups with many-many relation-ship, if I initialize group child objects in user then again that group has users as child objects if I initialize that it will go into cycle