# failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a restful web service for my database. I'm using jpa to retriving data from the db and spring for the architecture. I already tested the architecture with the basic dao queries (findById, save...) and it works perfectly. Then in the dao implementation I added a new method wich basically execute a query that is tested directly on the mysql db (and it worked)

```
public List<PositionHistory> findByFavUserGBuser(Integer favoriteUserId,
        Integer pageNumber, Integer rowsPerPage, String usernameFilter) {
    String queryString="" +
            "SELECT ph.* " +
            "FROM user u, position_history ph, spot s " +
            "WHERE " +
                "ph.date IN (SELECT MAX(ph2.date) FROM position_history ph2 GROUP BY ph2.user_iduser) and " +
                "s.id_spot=ph.spot_idspot and " +
                "u.id_user=ph.user_iduser and  ";

    if (usernameFilter!=null)
        queryString+="u.username like '%:usernameFilter%' and ";

    queryString+="" +
                "ph.user_iduser IN (SELECT ALL fu.user_iduserto FROM favorite_user fu WHERE fu.user_iduserfrom=:favoriteUserId) " +
            "GROUP BY ph.user_iduser " +
            "LIMIT :startLimit,:rowsPerPage";

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString,PositionHistory.class);
    query.setParameter("favoriteUserId", favoriteUserId);
    query.setParameter("startLimit", pageNumber*rowsPerPage);
    query.setParameter("rowsPerPage", rowsPerPage);

    if (usernameFilter!=null)
        query.setParameter("usernameFilter", usernameFilter);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

and then I created a controller to retrive data as follow:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    public DaoPositionHistory dph;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<PositionHistory> home(@PathVariable int id) {
        List<PositionHistory> resultlist=(List<PositionHistory>) dph.findByNearestPositionGBuser(id, 0, 10, null, null, null);
        return resultlist;
    }
}
```

but when i call the service i get the following error:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.windy.spring.data.User.favoriteSports, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.windy.spring.data.User.favoriteSports, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StdContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(StdContainerSerializers.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can not understand why I get this error if i declared the methos as @transactional? Any idea on how I can solve the problem?

Here is also my User class

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_user")
    private int idUser;

    private String cellphone;

    private String email;

    @Lob()
    private byte[] foto;

    private String name;

    private String notes;

    private String password;

    private String surname;

    private String username;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FavoriteSport
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<FavoriteSport> favoriteSports;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FavoriteSpot
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<FavoriteSpot> favoriteSpots;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FavoriteUser
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user2")
    private List<FavoriteUser> favoriteUsers;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Role
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="role_idrole")
    private Role role;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserAccount
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserAccount> userAccounts;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getIdUser() {
        return this.idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getCellphone() {
        return this.cellphone;
    }

    public void setCellphone(String cellphone) {
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return this.notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<FavoriteSport> getFavoriteSports() {
        return this.favoriteSports;
    }

    public void setFavoriteSports(List<FavoriteSport> favoriteSports) {
        this.favoriteSports = favoriteSports;
    }

    public List<FavoriteSpot> getFavoriteSpots() {
        return this.favoriteSpots;
    }

    public void setFavoriteSpots(List<FavoriteSpot> favoriteSpots) {
        this.favoriteSpots = favoriteSpots;
    }

    public List<FavoriteUser> getFavoriteUsers() {
        return this.favoriteUsers;
    }

    public void setFavoriteUsers(List<FavoriteUser> favoriteUsers) {
        this.favoriteUsers = favoriteUsers;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<UserAccount> getUserAccounts() {
        return this.userAccounts;
    }

    public void setUserAccounts(List<UserAccount> userAccounts) {
        this.userAccounts = userAccounts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out from reading the other answers to your question.  Just in case anyone needs it here is an example:

```
@Override
public OriginServer get(Integer id){
    OriginServer server = (OriginServer) sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession().get(OriginServer.class, id);
    Hibernate.initialize(server.getPools());
    return server;
}
```

In this example 'getPools' is a @OneToMany relationship from OriginServer.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace clearly shows that the exception occurs *after* the controller method has completed (and the transaction closed).

So either use an extended persistence context (where sessions live longer than transactions), access the lazy collection before the controller method returns, modify your DAO or mapping to load the collection eagerly, or don't return an object containing that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are not initializing entity associations in your DAO, and then the Jackson converter is trying to convert all associations in your return object to JSON.  Since the associations are not initialized, the error is thrown since your `Controller` doesn't have a handle to the Hibernate `Session`.

See my answer here for how to correct: [Spring @ResponseBody Json Cyclic Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727279/spring-responsebody-json-cyclic-reference/9759197#9759197)