# Jackson - serialization of entities with birectional relationships (avoiding cycles)

Tags: java, json, jackson, cycle, bidirectional-relation

I have two entities:

```
Parent {
   Child[] children;
}

and 

Child {
   Parent parent;
}
```

I'm aware about `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`.
They are good, if I'm serializing instances of `Parent`.

But I also need to transfer instances of `Child` and I want to have the `parent` field populated.

In other words:

1. On serialization of `Parent` it should have `children` but their parent field might be empty (can be solved by using json reference annotations).
2. On serialization of `Child` it should have `parent` with their `children` (but `children` don't have to have `parent` populated.

Is there a way to solve it using standard Jackson capabilities?

I.e. skip serialization of entities which were already serialized instead of marking fields eligible or non-eligible for serialization.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Jackson 2.0 does support full cyclic object references. See "[Jackson 2.0 released](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_466.html)" (section 'Handle Any Object Graphs, even Cyclic ones!') for an example.

Basically, you will need to use new `@JsonIdentityInfo` for types that require id/idref style handling. In your case this would be both `Parent` and `Child` types (if one extends the other, just add it to super type and that's fine).

Comment: Pretty fresh release. Requires some package moving. OK, I'll check it out.

Comment: Yeah, it is, big upgrade. But feature itself is big too. :-)

Comment: How do you deserialize using JSON2 in JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry -- Jackson 2.0 is just version of library; result is just regular JSON. But as to how to resolve references, for that you would need a matching javascript library: JSON format does not have anything to explicitly help in resolving deps.

Comment: I have a similar problem but with no luck after trying this solution :http://stackoverflow.com/q/36809325/3300911

Comment: Any idea plz on eat cud b the problem

Comment: doesn't helped with hibernate mapping

Comment: @StaxMan it will create IDs if the pojo already exists. How to avoid it ? I have created one issue regarding that. can you please help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078057/unable-to-deserialize-json-that-contain-2-objects-with-the-same-id-using-jackson

Comment: This is a solid answer, just want to add to be careful if using Lombok! Add "@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"fieldInRelationship"})" to both classes or those annotations will be ignored as was happening in my case!

Answer (score 33):

very handy interface implementation is provided in jackson 2 library as

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Parent { ....

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Child { ....
```

in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

@StaxMan provided a nice link to start from

Comment: further supportive reading http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

Comment: doesn't help with hibernate mapping

Comment: This link describes with few more details: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.0

Comment: You rock! Searched the internet for this problem. Finally found a solution. Big thanks!

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me for Spring Data MongoDB DBRef Two way referencing. Thanks!!