# Jackson JSON serialization, recursion avoidance by level defining

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I use Jackson library for serialization of my pojo objects into `JSON` representation. 
For example I have class A and class B:

```
class A {
  private int id;
  private B b;

  constructors...
  getters and setters
}

class B {
  private int ind;
  private A a;

  constructors...
  getters and setters
}
```

If I want to serialize object from class A there is certain possibility to get recursion while it is serialized. I know i can stop it by using `@JsonIgnore`.

**Is it possible to limit the serialization by depth-level ?**

For example, if the level is 2, the serialization will go this way:

- serialize a, level = 0 (0 < 2 ok) - > serialize
- serialize a.b, level =1
  (1 < 2 ok) -> serialize
- serialize a.b.a, level = 2 (2 < 2 not true) ->
  stop

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a way finally to specify the recursion depth that for which you wanted the serialization to happen?

Comment: I solved by using @JsonIgnore on the referenced entities(with recursion), so simply I don't include into the serialization. When I need the specific instance I already have the ID and I make additional call to get the instance. I did not used a general solution, luckily I have few cases.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar problem: Jackson - [serialization of entities with birectional relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc) (avoiding cycles)

So the solution is to upgrade to Jackson 2.0, and add to classes the following annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
                  property = "@id")
public class SomeEntityClass ...
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: this is really nice way. but do you know a way of limiting the deepness of the graph?

Comment: Nice, thanks. Note: the default value of property is "@id", so it could be omitted here (see source of JsonIdentityInfo => String property() default "@id";)

Answer (score 13):

Check the following links, it might help :

- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences
- [How to solve circular reference in json serializer caused by hibernate bidirectional mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340485/how-to-solve-circular-reference-in-json-serializer-caused-by-hibernate-bidirecti)

The only option after that would be to create your own custom module for serialization/deserialisation for your object type. see here:

- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers
- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for level-based ignorals.

But you can get Jackson to handle cyclic references with 2.0, see for example "[Jackson 2.0 released](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_466.html)" for explanation on how to use `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Comment: can you give some pointers here. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824858/writing-custom-serializers-and-deseralizers-recursive-implementations

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit yourself to only one level (ie : you go to the children of the current object and not further), there is a simple solution with @JsonView.

On every field that is a link to another object, annotate it with the current class as your view :

```
class A {
  private int id;
  @JsonView(A.class) private B b;

  constructors...
  getters and setters
}

class B {
  private int ind;
  @JsonView(B.class) private A a;

  constructors...
  getters and setters
}
```

Then, when serializing, use the object class as your view. Serializing an instance of A would render something like that :

```
{
  id: 42,
  b: {
    id: 813
  }
}
```

Make sure the DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is set to true, or the fields without a @JsonView annotation will not be rendered. Alternatively, you can annotate all other fields with @JsonView using the Object class, or any common super-class :

```
class A {
  @JsonView(Object.class) private int id;
  @JsonView(A.class) private B b;

  constructors...
  getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For depth wise  serialization,  you can refer to example here https://github.com/abid-khan/depth-wise-json-serializer

Answer (score 0):

For some cases you can limit serialization depth using a thread local integer holding max depth. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789537/3290316).

Answer (score 0):

After several months and a lot of research, I've implemented my own solution to keep my domain clear of jackson dependencies.

```
public class Parent {
    private Child child;
    public Child getChild(){return child;} 
    public void setChild(Child child){this.child=child;}
}

public class Child {
    private Parent parent;
    public Child getParent(){return parent;} 
    public void setParent(Parent parent){this.parent=parent;}
}
```

First, you have to declare each of your entities of the bidirectional relationship in something like this:

```
public interface BidirectionalDefinition {

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope=Parent.class)
    public interface ParentDef{};

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope=Child.class)
    public interface ChildDef{};

}
```

After that, the object mapper can be automatically configured:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Class<?>[] definitions = BidirectionalDefinition.class.getDeclaredClasses();
for (Class<?> definition : definitions) {
    om.addMixInAnnotations(definition.getAnnotation(JsonIdentityInfo.class).scope(), definition);
}
```