# Jackson/Jersey hide dynamically sublevels

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I have a Java servlet sending JSON with jackson/jersey.
I have to send a tree. This is my data structure.

```
public class Node {
    private String text;
    private String link;
    private List<Node> items;

    [...]
}
```

i.e i request `/` I want the first level only, answer should be :

```
    {
        "text":"toto",
        "link":"",
        "items":[{
            "text":"toutou",
            "link":"tata",
        ]}
    }
```

and if i request `/tata` answer should be :

```
    {
        "text":"toutou",
        "link":"tata",
        "items":[{
            "text":"toto2",
            "link":"toutou2",
        ]}
    }
```

So i only want to send 1 level of `items` because otherwise the JSON would be too big.
Is it possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question interested me so I started searching for recursive bean reference and how to avoid it using Jackson.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195575/1108032). I have not tried it, but it seems approved and appraised. Maybe it is worth trying. Please write back what happened, because I am also interested in the results.

Comment: I'm afraid the first part of his answer is more about bi directional relationship than my problem. Whereas implementing a custom module for serialization/deserialization I would have hope there was a simpler way, kinda of a dynamic JsonIgnore...

Comment: If you can formulate your requirement as a feature to implement, maybe file an RFE for Jackson?