# Bi-directional one-to-many relationship in google app engine using JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jackson, datanucleus

I want to create entity group in GAE Datastore such that one city have contain multiple suburbans. Following is my code :-

//city.java

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
@Entity
public class City
{
    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="city", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Suburban[] suburbans;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Suburban[] getSuburbans()
    {
        return suburbans;
    }

    public void setSuburbans(Suburban[] suburbans)
    {
        this.suburbans = suburbans;
    }

}
```

//suburban.java

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
@Entity
public class Suburban
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    public City getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Key getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I am auto-generating cityendpoint class using google-plugin for eclipse option "Generate Cloud Endpoint Class".

//CityEndpoint.java

```
@Api(name = "cityendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "zestbuds.com", ownerName = "zestbuds.com", packagePath = "android"))
public class CityEndpoint
{

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listCity")
    public CollectionResponse<City> listCity(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit)
    {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<City> execute = null;

        try
        {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from City as City");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "")
            {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null)
            {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<City>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (City obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<City> builder().setItems(execute).setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getCity")
    public City getCity(@Named("id") String id)
    {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        City city = null;
        try
        {
            city = mgr.find(City.class, id);
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param city the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertCity")
    public City insertCity(City city)
    {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try
        {
            if (containsCity(city))
            {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.persist(city);
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param city the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "updateCity")
    public City updateCity(City city)
    {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try
        {
            if (!containsCity(city))
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.persist(city);
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "removeCity")
    public void removeCity(@Named("id") String id)
    {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try
        {
            City city = mgr.find(City.class, id);
            mgr.remove(city);
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean containsCity(City city)
    {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try
        {
            City item = mgr.find(City.class, city.getName());
            if (item == null)
            {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Initally, I was not using @JsonIdentityInfo, and hence I was getting *java.io.IOException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)*. After reading [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032728/how-do-i-setup-a-manytoone-relationship-using-jpa-with-appengine), I recognized my error is due to jackson.

After reading [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097865/jackson-confused-with-bidirectional-one-to-many-relationship), I decided to use @JsonIdentityInfo. Now I am getting 
*java.io.IOException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: You have just attempted to access field "suburbans" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object. (through reference chain: com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse["items"]->com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult[0]->com.zestbuds.android.City["suburbans"])*

why am I getting suburban is not detached, even though I am using Cascade.ALL?

Answer (score 4):

Finally solved issue.

There is no need of using @JsonIdentityInfo . I just needed to remove getter and setter method for class member having @ManyToOne annotation(In my case, I removed getCity() and setCity()).

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/test/jpa/BidirectionalOneToManySubclassesJPA.java) is the example provided by datanucleus for bidirectional one-to-many mapping.