# How to serialize nested objects limiting depth of serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

There is a simple POJO - `Category` with `Set<Category>` as subcategories inside. Nesting might be quite deep as each of subcategories may contain sub-subcategories and so on.
I would like to return `Category` as REST resource via jersey, serialized to json (by jackson). The problem is, I can't really limit depth of serialization thus all the category tree gets serialized.

Is there any way to stop jackson serializing object just right after first level is completed (ie. `Category` with its first-level subcategories)?

Comment: Im not really familiar with the libraries you are using but, maybe mark the sub categories as transient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get current depth from a POJO you can do it with a ThreadLocal variable holding a limit. In a controller, before you return a Category instance set a depth limit on a ThreadLocal integer.

```
@RequestMapping("/categories")
@ResponseBody
public Category categories() {
    Category.limitSubCategoryDepth(2);
    return root;
}
```

In a subcategory getter you check depth limit against current depth of a category, if it's over the limit return null.

You'll need to clean up thread local somehow, perhaps with a spring's HandlerInteceptor::afterCompletition.

```
private Category parent;
private Set<Category> subCategories;

public Set<Category> getSubCategories() {
    Set<Category> result;
    if (depthLimit.get() == null || getDepth() < depthLimit.get()) {
        result = subCategories;
    } else {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}

public int getDepth() {
    return parent != null? parent.getDepth() + 1 : 0;
}

private static ThreadLocal<Integer> depthLimit = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static void limitSubCategoryDepth(int max) {
    depthLimit.set(max);
}

public static void unlimitSubCategory() {
    depthLimit.remove();
}
```

If you can't get depth from a POJO, you'll need to either make a tree copy with limited depth or learn how to code a custom Jackson serializer.