# Jackson annotations with hibernate orm

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have 2 classes. Parent & Child models(spring with hibernate).

A parent can have any number of children, each child has only one parent.

```
class Parent{
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
 private List<Child> children;
}

class Child{
 @ManyToOne
 Private Parent parent;
}
```

**Required Json output:**

1. When i request a **parent**, i should get all its **children** along with that, but each child **should not** contain its parent info again.
2. When i request for a **child**, i should get its **parent** along with that, but its parent should not contain all its children info.

What type of jackson annotations should i use for this

Comment: Related: [Jackson JSON serialization, recursion avoidance by level defining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10191671/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

refer @JsonView to generate different views of the same entity.

- when it is specified over a variable or getter it binds that variable to a view.
- when it is specified over a controller it defines which view to return for returned entity.