# Java jackson serialize ANY object with certain depth to avoid recursion

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am developing log library that serializes java objects into JSON, however, I faced with the problem that some objects can refer to themselves and eventually might recursively create infinite JSON. I need a functionality where I can specify the depth of serialization or somehow prevent recursion.
Can someone suggest any solution?

P.S. Jackson and GSON don't seem to have this functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191671/jackson-json-serialization-recursion-avoidance-by-level-defining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson JSON serialization, recursion avoidance by level defining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191671/jackson-json-serialization-recursion-avoidance-by-level-defining)