# Spring REST, JSON "Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference'" 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, spring-boot

I am trying to POST to http://localhost:9095/translators from an AngularJS front-end using Spring boot/Spring RestController backend.

I can do a GET and the response is like following:

```
[{"userId":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailId":"john.doe@inc.com","languages":[{"languageId":1,"languageCode":"gb","source":true}],"translations":[{"translationId":3,"sourceId":1,"sourceText":"Hello","targetId":null,"targetText":null,"translationStatus":"DUE"}],"userType":"TRANSLATOR"}
```

When I post the below json, I get the **error** response

*POST data:*

```
{
                    firstName: "zen",
                    lastName: "cv",
                    emailId: "email",
                    userType: "TRANSLATOR",
                    languages : [{languageId:1,languageCode:"gb",source:true}]
}
```

*Error:*

```
{
timestamp: 1422389312497
status: 415
error: "Unsupported Media Type"
exception: "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
message: "Content type 'application/json' not supported"
path: "/translators"
}
```

I have made sure that my controller has correct Mediatype annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/translators")
public class TranslatorController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List findUsers() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User findUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return repository.findOne(userId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public User addTranslator(@RequestBody User user) {
        //translation.setTranslationId(null);
        return repository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{translatorId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public User updateTranslation(@RequestBody User updatedUser, @PathVariable Long userId) {
        //updatedTranslation.setTranslationId(translationId);
        return repository.saveAndFlush(updatedUser);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{translatorId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteTranslation(@PathVariable Long translationId) {
        repository.delete(translationId);
    }
}
```

After some research and also by seeing log output, I realize that this is a misleading error message and the problem is in fact happening while serializing/deserializing Json

In log file, I find

> 2015-01-27 21:08:32.488  WARN 15152 --- [nio-9095-exec-1]
>   .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate
>   deserialization for type [simple type, class User]:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back
>   reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not
>   compatible with managed type (User)

Here is my class User and class Translation (getter, setter, constructor etc. omitted for brevity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "languages_users", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "lang_id")})
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "translator", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Translation> translations;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserType userType;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "translations")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "translation_id")
    private Long translationId;

    @Column(name = "source_lang_id")
    private Long sourceId;

    @Column(name = "source_text")
    private String sourceText;

    @Column(name = "target_lang_id")
    private Long targetId;

    @Column(name = "target_text")
    private String targetText;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private TranslationStatus translationStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "translator_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User translator;
}
```

My question is this: How can I correctly set JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference for the above entities? I did read the [doc.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences) and I cannot figure out what is wrong here based on the error message

Comment: Solved mine by removing `@JsonManagedReference` BUT keep` `@JsonBackReference`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it solved by getting rid of JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference and replacing it with JsonIdentityInfo

Comment: Did you remove all JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference annotations in parent and child classes?

Answer (score 20):

As @Sharppoint said in comments, I solved the mine by removing `@JsonManagedReference` BUT keep `@JsonBackReference`.

Comment: Worked for me too. Was facing exception of following form: `Cannot handle managed/back reference 'my-reference-name' value deserializer of type org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer does not support them`

Answer (score 12):

For those asking,
an alternative approach would be to use fasterxml's JsonIdentityInfo and to annotate your class with:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Account implements java.io.Serializable {
....
private Long id;
}
```

*Didnt have enough rep to comment.

Comment: thx. for the code. You can fetch the dead link from web archive (https://web.archive.org/web/20140314062757/http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/deserializing-objects-with-bi-directional-many-to-many-relations)

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to add a unique id for both of my classes, which I did via something like private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Answer (score 4):

You need `@ResponseBody` annotation like as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody public User addTranslator(@RequestBody User user) {
        //translation.setTranslationId(null);
        return repository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. I am still investigating, also whether my JSON post itself has problems

Comment: I'd guess that this comment applies if Jackson can't serialize a user object to JSON. In this question (and in my case), it seems Jackson isn't able to deserialize the input User object from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Can solve this by removing `JsonManagedReference` in the base class. `@JsonBackReference` does the work to stop recursing infinitely while getting/posting the data from the controller.

I am assuming that your Language class has multiple `@JsonBackReference` in it. So when you send the user data with two classes included in it, the spring is unable to deserialize the object and map it accordingly.

You can solve this by simply removing one of the `@JsonBackReference` from either Translation/Language classes and replacing it with `@JsonIgnore`/`@JsonIdentityInfo`.

This way, you're literally doing the same mapping but instead, you rule out the multiple `@JsonBackReference` to the base class which is clearly pointed out as an error resulting in `415 Unsupported media type exception`.

Comment: JsonIgnore / JsonBackRefrence these will not return the relation info in the JSON api will just remove the column so still we need to prevent the repeat and show the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, and I resolved removing all my annotations @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference, then I put @JsonIdentityInfo in all my clases with relationships
Check the  [Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140129235803/http://wiki.fasterxml.com:80/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity)

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to solve this problem is with `@JsonView`. The idea is that you label your controller with a view name and then label the properties you wish to be displayed for that view. You specifically do not expose the *backreferenced* properties to the calling view. An extremely simplified example below:

Imagine you had a 1 to 1 relationship like this. This would create a circular reference.

```java
@Entity
public class Student {

  String name;
  Tutor tutor;

}

@Entity
public class Tutor {
  String name;
  Student student;

}
```

You could now create views for them, almost the same way you do with `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty`.

#### Step 1. Create arbitrary empty interfaces that you can use to tag your controllers.

```java
public class LearningController {

  @GetRequest("/tutors")
  @JsonView(TutorView.class) // create an empty interface with a useful name
  public Set<Tutor> tutors() {
    return tutorRepository.findAll()
  }

  @GetRequest("/students")
  @JsonView(StudentView.class) // create an empty interface with a useful name
  public Set<Student> students() {
    return studentRepository.findAll()
  }
}
```

#### Step 2. Label the properties you want to expose (in any related / referenced class) to the view, also using the `@JsonView` annotation.

```java
@Entity
public class Student {

  @JsonView({StudentView.class, TutorView.class})
  String name;

  @JsonView({StudentView.class}) // Not visible to @TutorView (no backreference)
  Tutor tutor;

}

@Entity
public class Tutor {
  @JsonView({StudentView.class, TutorView.class})
  String name;
  @JsonView(TutorView.class) // Not visible to @StudentView (no backreference)
  Student student;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar case by adding @JsonIgnore