# problems storing data to data base in spring boot app

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-rest

I get an error while using post request to save data to the database in spring boot app.
I've many-to-many mappings between classes. I have no problems while fetching data from the database, but when I try to save data to the database I'm getting this error.

```
2018-06-26 12:19:32.016  WARN 3156 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.greydelta.entity.Permission]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.greydelta.entity.Role)
2018-06-26 12:19:32.018  WARN 3156 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.greydelta.entity.Permission]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.greydelta.entity.Role)
```

I'm using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` in parent and child entity classes.

Here are my mappings
`Child` class:

```
    // test this mapping
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="permissions",
        cascade={ CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JsonBackReference
private List<Role> roles;
```

`Parent` class:

```
    // test this mapping
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable( name="role_permission",
            joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="permission_id")})
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Permission> permissions; // create getter/setter
```

UPDATE:

Here is the URL I user to sent  POST request to create a role:
                    localhost:8080/roles

Here is the response which I get in Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-26T08:18:03.167+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/roles"
}
```

and Here is the controller method :

```
@PostMapping("/roles")
public void createRole(@RequestBody Role theRole) {     

    roleService.createRole(theRole);

}
```

Comment: what you show is only a warning. Do you have an indication of an actual problem? I guess you are "saving" by doing some kind of HTTP request. Could you show the curl statement or comparable you use?

Comment: @Jens Schauder, I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved this problem, by removing @JsonManagedReference.
If you have more than two entities that are mapped together then you need to remove @JsonManagedReference in every entity class. I found this solution here:

[Spring REST, JSON "Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference'" 415 Unsupported Media Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179369/spring-rest-json-can-not-handle-managed-back-reference-defaultreference-415).

I hope this helps.