# Failed to lazily initialize a collection.. no session or session was closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, jackson

I don't know what else to try, I've updated to Jackson 2, changed to Lazy, used @JsonIgnore... but nothing worked out. Any idea what can it be?

**Environment**

- Spring MVC 3.2.5
- Jackson 2.2
- Hibernate 3.5.4

**ERROR**
    Estado HTTP 500 - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["actions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.javalabs.web.dao.TaskAction["task"]->com.javalabs.web.dao.Task["actions"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["actions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.javalabs.web.dao.TaskAction["task"]->com.javalabs.web.dao.Task["actions"])

**Error trace**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["actions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.javalabs.web.dao.TaskAction["task"]->com.javalabs.web.dao.Task["actions"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["actions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.javalabs.web.dao.TaskAction["task"]->com.javalabs.web.dao.Task["actions"])
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:207)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
causa raíz

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["actions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.javalabs.web.dao.TaskAction["task"]->com.javalabs.web.dao.Task["actions"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:184)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:605)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:394)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:315)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:204)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
causa raíz

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javalabs.web.dao.Task.actions, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:90)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:394)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:315)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:204)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

**MODEL**

[image]

**TaskController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getactions/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getActions(Principal principal,
            @PathVariable Long id) {
        logger.info("Task controller get actions...");

        List<TaskAction> actions = null;

        if (principal == null) {
            actions = new ArrayList<TaskAction>();
        } else {
            actions = taskActionService.getAllTaskActions(id);
        }

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("actions", actions);
        data.put("number", actions.size());

        return data;
    }
}
```

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idTask")
    private long idTask;
    @Size(min = 5, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "taskname")
    private String taskname;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "task", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TaskAction> actions = new ArrayList<TaskAction>();
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Timestamp timestamp;
...
}
```

**User.java**
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idUser")
private long idUser;

...

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JsonIgnore
@JoinTable(name = "r_userrole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idUser") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idRole") })
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

...
}

**TaskAction.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_taskaction")
public class TaskAction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idTaskAction")
    private long idTaskAction;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTask", nullable = false)
    private Task task;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
    ...
}
```

**TaskActionDao.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("taskActionDao")
public class TaskActionDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    ...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TaskAction> getAllTaskActions() {
        Query q = session().createQuery("from TaskAction");
        List<TaskAction> la = q.list();
        //createQuery("from TaskAction").list();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>getAllActions>>>>>>>>>>> " + la.size());
        return la;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TaskAction> getAllTaskActions(long idTask) {
        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(TaskAction.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("task.idTask", idTask));
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>getAllActions(id)>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + crit.list().size());
        return crit.list();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about TaskAction.java?

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fist of all, we don't need User.java at all here. It has nothing to it. The issue is related to Task.actions. You load collection of TaskAction, TaskAction has Task and this Task has collection of TaskAction which cannot be initialized. You can add `@JsonIgnore` to:

```
private List<TaskAction> actions = new ArrayList<TaskAction>(); //Task class
```

or to:

```
private Task task; //TaskAction class
```

You can also try with changing `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER` for collection of actions in Task.java, however I'm not sure it's going to work (circular references)

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I've tried with @JsonIgnore it worked, but I do need actions information, and with FetchType.EAGER I had too much information, that I don't need and I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: Now I'm trying with @JsonIdentityInfo, it's a way to deal with circular refs.

Comment: Try with @JsonIgnoreProperties as well.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are accessing your Object outside the Hibernate Session object, so you should 
add the annotation @JsonIgnore before each @OneToMany annotation in your model

Answer (score 2):

Please add annotation @JsonIgnore before each @OneToMany annotation in you entity class 
My solution

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "domainDataId")
```

Thank Shahid Hussain Abbasi

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered a similar problem: Jackson version 1.9 and lower with birectional relationships (avoiding cycles)

And the solution seems to upgrade to Jackson 2.0, and add to classes the following annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
                  property = "idTaskAction")
public class TaskAction
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue showing the exception same as above, complaining about the 'no session' but I found that the problem was due to the Entity being referenced in the DTO rather than its ID. So just in case above problem occurs I will suggest to check if one hasn't caused any serialization issue.