# Custom Jackson serializing entities with one to many relationship

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, jackson

In the web project I use hiberante and jersey which in turn goes together with Jackson. For work with hiberante I have 3 entity-classes which reflect structure of tables of a database and have "one to many" and "many to one" relations. Binding fields are annotated as `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. Objects of these classes have to be serialized in json. For avoidance of mistakes during serialization binding fields were also annotated as `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.
As a result of serialization of object of the `Shops` class such line turned out:

```
{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Shop #2",
      "category": "auto",
      "distance": 120,
      "discounts": [
          {
              "id": 9,
              "title": "-50%",
              "startDate": 1425679200000,
              "endDate": 1425679200000
          }
      ]
 }
```

It didn't suit me and I decided to write the custom serializer. As a result I wanted to see the following json:

```
{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Shop #2",
      "category": "auto",
      "distance": 120,
      "locality_id": 10,
}
```

For this purpose I created 3 classes serializers for each of entity and cleaned annotations `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` which were earlier and added `@JsonSerialize` about the indication of a class serializer.

As a result in start attempt I receive the following mistake:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:189)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:216)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:117)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:73)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:19)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1052)
```

**How I can correct this error?**
Entity-classes and classes serializers are given below.

Entity-classes:

Localities

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalitiesSerializer.class)
@Table(name = "localities")
public class Localities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name",nullable=false, length=57)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "locality")
    private Set<Shops> shops = new HashSet<Shops>(0);

    //constructors, getters & setters
}
```

*Shops*

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = ShopsSerializer.class)
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shops {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name="name", length=45, nullable=false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name="category", columnDefinition="ENUM('undefined','auto','children_prod','food','game','book','electronics','beuty_and_health','fashion','footwear','clothing','sports','homewere','pet_prod','services','gift_and_flowers')",
            nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected Categories category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "locality_id", nullable = false)
    protected Localities locality;

    @Transient
    private Double distance;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "shop")
    private Set<Discounts> discounts = new HashSet<Discounts>(0);

    //constructors, getters & setters    
}
```

*Discount*

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = DiscountsSerializer.class)
@Table(name="discounts")
public class Discounts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
    private Calendar startDate;

    @Column(name="end_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
    private Calendar endDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id", nullable = false)
    private Shops shop;

    //constructors, getters & setters

}
```

Serializers:

*LocalitiesSerializer*

```
public class LocalitiesSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Localities> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Localities locality, JsonGenerator jsonGen,
            SerializerProvider serProv) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("id", locality.getId());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("name", locality.getName());
        jsonGen.writeEndObject();

    }
}
```

*ShopsSerializer*

```
public class ShopsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Shops> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Shops shop, JsonGenerator jsonGen,
            SerializerProvider serProv) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("id", shop.getId());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("name", shop.getName());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("category", shop.getCategory().toString());
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("distance", shop.getDistance());
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("locality_id", shop.getLocality().getId());
        jsonGen.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```

*DiscountsSerializer*

```
public class DiscountsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Discounts> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Discounts discount, JsonGenerator jsonGen,
            SerializerProvider serProv) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("id", discount.getId());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("title", discount.getTitle());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("start_date", discount.getStartDate().toString());
        jsonGen.writeStringField("end_date", discount.getEndDate().toString());
        jsonGen.writeNumberField("shop_id", discount.getShop().getId());
        jsonGen.writeEndObject();

    }
}
```

P.S. Annotation `@JsonIgnore` in this case doesn't approach as further I plan to clean annotations `@JsonSerialize` and to use classes serializers as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Item.class, new ShopsSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(shop);
```

Thus there is an opportunity to use different serializers.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference (as this was what I was looking for, but ended up here):
[Jackson - serialization of entities with birectional relationships (avoiding cycles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc)