# Querying using two-way referencing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jackson, spring-data-mongodb, dbref

I have two classes:

```
class Person {
  @DBRef
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Task> tasks;
}

class Task {
  @DBRef
  @JsonBackReference
  private Person person;
}
```

When I query to find all Persons the list of Tasks is populated with the associated Tasks. That's what I want.

When I query to find all Tasks, I expected to receive an Task object with the associate Person on it, but I'm receiving without the Person field as null. I want to receive the associated Person as well.

Comment: that is supposed to work as described. Can you share a bit more details on how you actually persist your data (code snipped, gist, whatever...) and which version of spring-data-mongodb you are using?

Comment: To save both Person and Task I'm using the ```mongoOperations.insert``` and passing the object as param.

I'm using the version ```1.6.1.RELEASE``` of spring-data-mongodb.

Comment: I found this question and it's basically what I want to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc

The answer talks about using ```@JsonIdentityInfo```. I tried but with no luck. Didn't figure out which Generator I should use.